# Can anyone explain what how customized theme should be set up in design tab M2

Tags: magento-2.1, custom, design

[image: my design config tab]

I have three listings and I do not understand how these work or how I should be setting these up to use my customized theme Cool. I have just one store and one website. Should I have all three of these entries set to my customized theme or just one or just two?
Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one website and store then you have to set you theme at 1st Global and if you have more than one website and store then you can change theme store and website wise.

You can create website, store and store view at `store->configuration`. once you create them then you can set custom theme and their Other Settings as well, store wise and website wise.

Further information read this doc [How to apply and configure a storefront theme?](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-apply.html)